# Extracting tabular data with its formatting and styles from Outlook to Excel using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

You guys are doing great job by helping newbie coders. This is my first question, apologies if its not as per required guidelines.

Can you please help me to advise how can we extract tabular data from outlook with its **styles and formatting** to paste in excel.

Currently i am able to extract tabular data from outlook email but after i take it on excel its formatting  and styles are lost.

I searched in google but could not find anything specific on this.

I have project to complete , please help.

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client
outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
namespace=outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

Crome=namespace.Folders['ABC'].Folders['XYZ']
Crome_list=[x for x in Crome.items]

for msg in Crome_list:
    if "DEF" in msg.Subject:
        df=pd.read_html(msg.HTMLBody)[0]
        pqr=pd.DataFrame(df)
        pqr.to_excel('test.xlsx',index=False,header=False)
```